# Filter Node Reference options

Tags: nodes, input-formats

I'm trying to set up the content types for a site and ran into a bit of a problem.
Let's say I have a content type called Employee, and a list of taxonomy terms that holds function names.
Each employee is linked to a function so to say using a Term Reference to one of the available function. Like this each employee is either a mananger, a desk employee, or a janitor etc.

In a second content type, I wish to add a node reference to these Employee nodes, but I wish to have the option of only selecting the nodes linked to a certain term, such as manager. As such, when creating a new node of this second content type I should only be able to select managers in my overview.

Is there any way of filtering your available options like this? I saw some other questions mentioning the References module, but these questions didn't have an answer.

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) Module you can set up a view that pulls in a list of entities and then use that view to select the nodes. Steps:

1. Create a view of employees
2. Add a contextual filter to the view for has term reference
3. Save view.
4. Add entity reference filed and select use view to show results.

Hope that helps